# How to edit my duplicates

Tags: modeling

i have built an apartment complex out of many planes.  So rather than just making 4 planes for a house like this noob normal does, I used shift d duplicate in object mode.  Now in edit mode all of my duplicated planes don't have any vertices,edges, or faces.  After looking online, tried deleting all doubles which I had none.  so I asking for help on what I did wrong using duplicate.  I was in object mode, hit shift d, hit enter, then moved the duplicated plane to a new location.      i am using 2.79b

Comment: If there is geometry in object mode, but not in edit mode, it could be hidden. Have you tried unhiding with Alt H? Are there any modifiers on your objects?

Comment: Try alt H, no luck.  no modifiers,  There is nothing but objects so far.  very bare bones that's what concerns me.  I think it's going to be several hours down the drain but I am eager to try anything if I can save it,  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Please show your work as a Blender screen capture.  Please show your work in all future questions.  Carefully pick you screen captures to help the reader solve your problems.

Answer (score 1):

I think we're going to need more details and possibly the file, because this is likely something very simple.

1st- how did you create the plane? Was it Add>Plane?
2nd- Did you do anything to the plane before duplicating it, like some modeling?
3rd- At the top right corner, it should let you know how many faces, vertices, etc. there are on the selected object in edit mode. When you get into edit mode how many faces does it say are there?
4th- Did you apply any modifiers and duplicate that with the plane?